# Cambiar el valor de un elemento en un diccionario en Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Estoy empezando a trabajar con diccionarios en Python, por lo que me surgió un problema a la hora de imprimir por pantalla el resultado de una operación, pero no obtengo el esperado.

Teniendo una determinada "data" (un diccionario), necesito cambiar el valor de la clave "name" y concatenarlo con un número X de valores de otra clave del diccionario, obteniendo como resultado X elementos resultantes de concatenar los dos elementos, para enviar el diccionario a otra función, para que luego `name`vuelva a tomar el valor inicial (`nombre`), itere y coja el siguiente valor, y así hasta finalizar el bucle, enviando así 5 diccionarios a la función, cada uno con un valor distinto de `name`.

Les dejo el código que he realizado:

```py
data = {
  'name': 'nombre',
  'recurso': 'recurso {}'
}

for val in range(5):
  data_name = data['name'] + "_" + data['recurso'].format(val).replace(" ","")
  data['name'] = data_name

  print(data['name'])

  create_package(data)
```

Con mi código, obtengo como resultado:

```
nombre_recurso0
nombre_recurso0_recurso1
nombre_recurso0_recurso1_recurso2
nombre_recurso0_recurso1_recurso2_recurso3
nombre_recurso0_recurso1_recurso2_recurso3_recurso4
```

El resultado que espero es el siguiente:

```
nombre_recurso0
nombre_recurso1
nombre_recurso2
nombre_recurso3
nombre_recurso4
```

Gracias de antemano.

Por lo tanto, el diccionario en cada iteración debería quedar así:

```py
data = {'name':nombre_recurso0, 'recurso': recurso 0}
# Enviar a función create_package(data)

data = {'name':nombre_recurso1, 'recurso': recurso 1}
# Enviar a función create_package(data)

data = {'name':nombre_recurso2, 'recurso': recurso 2}
# Enviar a función create_package(data)

data = {'name':nombre_recurso3, 'recurso': recurso 3}
# Enviar a función create_package(data)

data = {'name':nombre_recurso4, 'recurso': recurso 4}
# Enviar a función create_package(data)
```

Comment: ¿Se supone que las claves de `data` serían `nombre_0`, `nombre_1`,....`nombre_5`?

Comment: @ChemaCortes no, las claves serían ```name``` y ```recurso```

Comment: ¡Pero sólo hay una clave `name` que cambias 5 veces! ¿Es eso lo que quieres?¿El resultado esperado es un diccionario o imprimir 5 valores?

Comment: @ChemaCortes lo que busco es únicamente imprimir, no devolver un diccionario, solo imprimir 5 veces la modificación del valor de ```name``` tal como dije en la pregunta

Comment: Pero es algo absurdo. Si cambias el diccionario, pierdes el valor original. A no ser que lo guardes en otra variable, con lo que no entiendo qué necesitas realmente.

Comment: @ChemaCortes lo de guardar el valor original en una variable me ha dado una idea, y funciona, así que muchas gracias indirectamente! :) Perdona si te estaba liando, soy un poco nuevo con esto y los términos y las acciones no las controlo bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nueva respuesta en base a lo nuevo solicitado:

**En base a lo nuevo que intentas hacer, tengo la siguiente solución:**

```
data = {
  'name': 'nombre',
  'recurso': 'recurso {}'
}

for val in range(5):
  data2 = data.copy()
  data2['name'] = data2['name'] + "_" + data2['recurso'].format(val).replace(" ","")
  create_package(data2)
```

- En esta solución por cada iteración realizamos una copia de data, sobre la cual trabajaremos y aplicaremos los cambios que desea, para posteriormente pasar este nuevo diccionario a tu función.

**Si hace un print a data2, obtienes:**

```
{'name': 'nombre_recurso0', 'recurso': 'recurso {}'}
{'name': 'nombre_recurso1', 'recurso': 'recurso {}'}
{'name': 'nombre_recurso2', 'recurso': 'recurso {}'}
{'name': 'nombre_recurso3', 'recurso': 'recurso {}'}
{'name': 'nombre_recurso4', 'recurso': 'recurso {}'}
```

---

### Respuesta anterior en base a imprimir:

**La solución es la siguiente:**

```
data = {
  'name': 'nombre',
  'recurso': '{} recurso'
}


for val in range(5):
  data_name = data['name'] + "_" + data['recurso'].format(val).replace(" ","")

  print(data_name )
```

- De esta forma imprimirás el nuevo nombre de la clave.

**Realizando lo anterior obtienes esto:**

```
nombre_0recurso
nombre_1recurso
nombre_2recurso
nombre_3recurso
nombre_4recurso
```

Comment: Obviamente la finalidad de esto es que cambie el diccionario, pero quería mostrar por pantalla el resultado. Tengo que enviar el diccionario como parámetro a otra función, por lo que necesito que cuando ```name``` tome el valor, por ejemplo, ```nombre_1recurso```, se envíe este diccionario a la función, para que luego, ```name``` tome el valor inicial (```nombre```), vuelva a iterarse y coja el valor ```nombre_2recurso```, se vuelva a enviar el diccionario y así hasta que finalice la iteración. Lo siento si me expliqué mal.

Comment: Ya cambié la pregunta, perdón.

Comment: Modifique la respuesta, en base a lo que quieres alcanzar como solución.

Answer (score 0):

Si como dices en un comentario, sólo quieres imprimir el resultado, no tienes porqué cambiar el diccionario.

Reusando tu código:

```py
data = {
  'name': 'nombre',
  'recurso': 'recurso {}'
}

for val in range(5):
  data_name = data['name'] + "_" + data['recurso'].format(val).replace(" ","")
#  data['name'] = data_name

#  print(data['name'])
  print(data_name)
```

Comment: Perdona, que tuve una confusión. Lo de imprimirlo es solo para ver que el resultado del cambio de ```name```es el que espero, pero necesito enviar ese diccionario a una función al final del bucle, teniendo ```name```, por ejemplo, el valor ```nombre_recurso1```, enviar el diccionario y luego, volver a tener el valor inicial de ```name```, que sería ```nombre```, para volver a hacer la operación, que tome el valor ```nombre_recurso2```, volver a enviar el diccionario y así hasta finalizar el bucle. Perdón por liarte.

Comment: Ya cambié la pregunta, perdón.